# First table font colour getting dark using itext in pdf

Tags: java, android, itext

I am developing android application requirement to create tables in pdf, using `itextpdf5.3.4`.

I am having problem related to table in pdf. I am creating 25 records in one table at absolute position.if am having more than 25 records means creating one more table in new page. If I am having two tables, the text in first table which is getting dark font.

Below I am pasting my code:

```
Document document = new Document();

try {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/report.pdf");
    initializeFonts();
    Font hedder_font= new Font(bfBold, 8);
    Font content_font = new Font(bf, 8);
    Font color_font = new Font(bf, 8);
    color_font.setColor(new BaseColor(0,172,237));
    PdfWriter docWriter= PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    docWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(true);
    BaseReportBuilder event = new BaseReportBuilder();
    docWriter.setPageEvent(event);
    document.open();

    PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        createHeadings(cb,25,620,"Details",10,bfBold);
    }

    //list all the products sold to the customer
    float[] columnWidths = {0.5f,3f, 1f, 1f,1f};
    //create PDF table with the given widths
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    // set table width a percentage of the page width
    table.setTotalWidth(500f);

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sr",hedder_font));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item ",hedder_font));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date",hedder_font));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("id",hedder_font));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Amount",hedder_font));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    if (list.size() > 25) {
        int value =630;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            System.out.println("i" + i);
            value = value - 15;
            String date = list.get(i).getCreated_on();
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(i+1),content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getItem(),content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(date,content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getCategory_name(), content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getAmount(), content_font)));
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(),610, docWriter.getDirectContent());

        }
        document.newPage();

        //create PDF table with the given widths
        PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
        // set table width a percentage of the page width
        table1.setSpacingAfter(250f); 
        table1.setTotalWidth(500f);
        for (int i = 25; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String date = list.get(i).getCreated_on();
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(i+1),content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getItem(), content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(date,content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getItemid(), content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getAmount(), content_font)));
        }
        //absolute location to print the PDF table from 
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total",content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("",content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("",content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("",content_font)));
            table1.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""+""+total,hedder_font)));
        }

        document.add(table1);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("i"+i);
            String date = list.get(i).getCreated_on();
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(i+1),content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getItem(),content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(date,content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getItemid(), content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(list.get(i).getAmount(), content_font)));
        }
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total",content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("",content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("",content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("",content_font)));
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""+""+total,hedder_font)));}
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(),610, docWriter.getDirectContent());
        }
        System.out.println("docWriter.getVerticalPosition(true)" + docWriter.getVerticalPosition(true));

        if (docWriter.getVerticalPosition(true) < 100) {
            document.newPage();
        }
        createHeadings(cb,30,100,"Number of items : " +list.size(),12,bfBold);
        createHeadings(cb,495,100,": " +list.size(),11,bfBold);
        createHeadings(cb,350,75,"Total :",11,bfBold);
        createHeadings(cb,495,75,": " +total,12,bfBold);
        document.close();
    } 
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
private void initializeFonts() {

    try {

        bfBold = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        bf =BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where are `bf` and `bfBold` defined? What do you mean by *dark font*? Do you mean bold font? What text has this *dark font*? You'll have to clarify that by editing your question.

Comment: Also, you definitely should slim down your code snippet to a minimal example showing the issue. To start with, remove the section about the logo, and probably all the `createHeadings(...)` calls, since that's unlikely to have any relation to your issue.

Comment: thanks for suggestion,edited the code bf is normal helvitica font and bfbold is bold version

Comment: cell text in table getting dark font

Comment: What text? What do you mean by dark? Black? Not coloured?

Comment: Please check the link i placed pdf in dropbox [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/tif5obzn0a1emqa/Result.pdf?dl=0)